# No method named to_str found for type Option<&std::ffi::OsStr>?

Tags: rust

Here is my current attempt at iterating through a directory and adding filetype extensions to a map and counting how many files have that extension type.

The call to `to_str()` fails because

```
no method named `to_str` found for type `std::option::Option<&std::ffi::OsStr>` in the current scope [E0599]
```

I tried converting to a string elsewhere, I tried not even evaluating the `Option` and trying to just insert it as-is into the map, but that didn't work either.

```
extern crate walkdir;

use std::ffi::OsStr;
use std::path::Path;
use walkdir::WalkDir;

extern crate serde_json;
use serde_json::{Map, Number, Value};

fn main() {
    let mut map = Map::new();
    let walker = WalkDir::new("/Users/jamescampbell/").into_iter();
    for entry in walker {
        let entry = entry.unwrap();
        let os_str = OsStr::new(entry.file_name());
        let path = Path::new(os_str);
        let extensioner = path.extension();
        let my_new_string: String = match extensioner.to_str() {
            None => String::from("crap, os_str failed"),
            Some(s) => s,
        };
        println!("should be foo: {}", my_new_string);
        if !map[s] {
            map.insert(s.to_string(), Value::Number(Number::from(1u64)));
        } else {
            map[s] += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of issues.

The first one is that the result of `extension()` is an `Option<T>`. Specifically, its a `Option<&std::ffi::OsStr>`. So you must unwrap it:

That isn't the only issue though, because calling `to_str()` on an `&OsStr` will return a `Option<&str>`, which itself is also not a `String`.

Leaving out all of the potential ignored issues with the conversions between string types ... this is a minimal recreation of the part that is causing you issues:

```
use std::path::Path;
use std::ffi::OsStr;

fn main() {
    let os_str = OsStr::new("example.txt");
    let path = Path::new(os_str);
    let extensioner = path.extension();
    let my_new_string: String = extensioner.unwrap().to_str().unwrap().into();

    println!("Extension: {}", my_new_string);
}
```

[Here it is running on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dfe613ec145b9d4ca707568187e5dc3a)

Basically, we:

- `unwrap` the `Option<&OsStr>` into an `&OsStr`.
- Call `to_str()` on the `&OsStr`
- `unwrap` the resulting `Option<&str>` into an `&str`
- Call `into()`, which will convert it into a `String` (this invokes the `From` trait implementation of `String`)